# Python how to get value from argparse from variable, but not the name of the variable?

Tags: python, string, argparse

If I do args.svc_name, I was expecting equivalent to args.option1, because the svc_name's value is option1. But i got error for "'Namespace' object has no attribute 'svc_name's'"

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=None,description="test")   
parser.add_argument("--option1", nargs="?",help="option")
args = parser.parse_args()
svc_name = "option1"
print (args.svc_name)
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `ArgumentParser` class exposes the keys as direct attributes rather than a mapping, so to get the attribute directly one would simply access it directly.  As per the example from the question, it would simply be

```
print(args.option1)
```

If one wish to have some other variable (e.g. `svc_name` from the question) to store the attribute/flag to acquire the value from the argparser, simply turn it into a mapping (i.e. `dict`) using [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars) and then call the get method

```
print(vars(args).get(svc_name))
```

Or alternatively, `getattr(args, svc_name)`.

Comment: Thanks. Just note (for my case) that `--num-max` will translate into `args.num_max` (i.e. dashes are converted to underscores).

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Yup, as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest) - "Any internal `-` characters will be converted to `_` characters to make sure the string is a valid attribute name"; moreover, if `dest` is supplied, that will be the corresponding attribute name.