# Get arguments from ArgumentParser without calling parse_args

Tags: python, argparse, uvicorn

I have the following code and I want to use to extract the `config` parameter.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument(
    "--config", 
    type=str, 
    default="src/config.yml",
    dest="config"
)
```

My issue is that I cannot use `parser.parse_args()` (because I'm running the script from `uvicorn` and the `parse_args` is raising an error. Is there a way to retrieve the `config` parameter without the use of `parse_args`?

---

[Other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624460/python-how-to-get-value-from-argparse-from-variable-but-not-the-name-of-the-var) I've seen make use of `parse_args`.

Comment: Given that `parse_args` does the parsing of sys.argv and you can’t use it then presumably you’ll have to parse sys.argv yourself - have you tried to do that? Or perhaps you can adapt what is (I guess) a non-standard sys.argv to something that parse_args() can handle? To do that you’ll have to look at sys.argv.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What do you mean by the `config` parameter?  Do you want the value that the parser would find in the `sys.argv`?  Or do you want the corresponding `Action` object?  Or its `default` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse an argument array that is not passed via `sys.argv`, for example one that you created, simply pass an array to the [parse_args()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) function.

```py
my_args = ["--config", "my_value"]
parsed_args = parser.parse_args(my_args)

print(parsed_args.config)  # Prints "my_value"
```

Comment: No, they seem to suggest that `parse_args()` does not support what they need, which I would guess it does when reading their question.

Edit: More specifically: They say `parse_args()` raises an error, which I guess is due to `sys.argv` not being filled by uvicorn.

Comment: Then according to your code, they pass `my_args = ["--config", "my_value"]` in order to get `"my_value"`. But they would already have that value so why use `argparse` at all?

Comment: Mine is a toy example. Presumably they get arguments from somewhere and want to use `argparse` to verify their validity. They can do that by passing them directly.

For example, their example checks for the type (str) and has a default that is assigned if no value is given. Yes, to preempt your obvious next comment, that could be done differently. I know that, I know Python. I'm just trying to help this person with their specific issue.

Why does this bother you so much? I'm puzzled.